# Filtering out service provider files from META-INF

Tags: java, ant, jar, jersey

My application needs to run both from the command-line and a web app.  The way I've chosen to implement this is to have the entire application in a single jar file (i.e. my application-specific classes coexist with the classes from the jars my app uses).  This makes the command-line use case simple, as the user only has to type `java -jar JARNAME`.  For the web app use case, I simply include the jar in `WEB-INF/lib` and all is well, almost.

The problem I have is that a few of the jars I'm slurping into the single jar define providers in `META-INF/services` for the same service, so the single jar ends up with multiple entries in `META-INF/services` with the same name.  (For the curious, these are Jersey jars, and the services are `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader` and `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter`.)  So I'm trying to prevent the MessageBody* service files from being slurped into my jar file.  Here's how I'm trying (and failing) to accomplish that:

```
<jar destfile="build/jammies.jar">
    <archives>
        <zips>
            <restrict>
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                    <exclude name="servlet-api.jar"/>
                </fileset>
                <rsel:not>
                    <rsel:name regex="META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.*"/>
                </rsel:not>
            </restrict>
        </zips>
    </archives>
</jar>
```

I do have the `rsel` namespace defined at the top of `build.xml`.

```
<project basedir="." default="compile" 
    xmlns:rsel="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors">
```

So I don't understand why the `restrict` task isn't filtering out those particular service provider files.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the regex starts matching the filename strings from the start however no file begins with META-INF, they would begin with ${basedir}/WEB-INF/lib/META-INF...

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It's been so long since I originally posted this that I don't even know which project I was working on when I had the problem, so I won't be able to upvote your response.